# extending FilterDispatcher struts2

Tags: utf-8, struts2, servlet-filters

In my project code I can see `FilterDispatcher` being extended to set the default encoding as "UTF-8". My question is there any other better way we can do the same or this is the best way.

PS: The initial development was done in a country on Non-English windows PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is `struts.i18n.encoding` constant which sets default locale and encoding scheme. You can set it in `struts.properties` file:

```
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```

or in `struts.xml` file:

```
<constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
```

BTW: `struts.i18n.encoding` should be set to `UTF-8` by default in Struts2 anyway.

BTW no.2: `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3. So if you using version higher than that use `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` instead.

Comment: The project uses Struts 2.0. So it actually mens that it was an unnecessary approach taken.Thanks a Lot.